# Compiling and installing openssl On windows 64 bit

Tags: compilation, openssl, mingw, msys

I wanted to install openssl on windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit , i have downloaded the openssl package and extracted it as well in the c directory however i am not able to find something that shows how to link the openssl in Netbeans 7.1.1 . I have got MinGW(4.6.1) compiler with MSYS .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please read INSTALL.W32 file in OpenSSL that explains the build procedure with different development suite.

In this file you will find

```
   GNU C (MinGW/MSYS)
```

It explains the procedure to build it using MinGW with MSYS.

To use it in Netbeans, you need to mention the include path of OpenSSL header files (generated during library compilation) and path of OpenSSL library. I never used Netbeans, so I do not know about it. You need to mention include and library in project settings.